# WP_Query not returning any posts

Tags: wp-query

I'm used to writing complex WP queries, but am currently stumped. On a new website I have a dozen published posts, but the basic loop in WordPress doesn't find them.

```
 <?php

$the_query = new WP_Query($args);

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
         echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
} else {
   echo 'no posts found';
 }
wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```

I just get "no posts found" returned. What could the issue be?

Comment: What's in `$args`? If there are no posts matching the arguments specified, of course there will be no posts returned. Other than that it's hard to say with just the info given. Perhaps the posts are retrieved but you can see them because the `<ul>` is missing from the markup. Generally, I think we need more info here.

Comment: Yeah, you will need to define $args and at least specify a post type. Here is the documentation https://www.billerickson.net/code/wp_query-arguments/

Comment: Where are you using this loop?